# Проблема с переводом в админке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, сервер

Столкнулся с проблемой в админке wp
Переводы не подтягиваются корректно (насколько мне известно, переводы работают при помощи __() и берутся из файлов). Часть текста либо не переведена, либо вырвана из середины. Если включить английский язык, то, соответственно, подобной проблемы нет. Честно говоря, ни разу с подобным не сталкивался.
На локальной машине (openserver) все работает корректно, но когда залил на сервак (isp) в админке появились подобные проблемы. Переносом раньше занимался не один раз, так что вряд ли проблема именно в кривом переносе, тем более, что переводы не в бд хранятся, а сравнение файлов с локальной версией различий не нашло.
Начинаю грешить на сервак, может быть какие-то параметры установлены не те? Попытался с нуля на тот же сервер пустой вордпресс поставить, уже со стартовой страницы полезли приколы - перевода нет (хотя качал русскую версию), ну и съехавшие переводы в т.ч.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень странное поведение. Переводы не из файлов сейчас, а грузятся с сервера. Но не суть. Как переносили?

Comment: Похоже на поврежденную базу. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Comment: База битая 100%. Кури ссылку выше.

Comment: базу переносил уже десятки раз, так что знаю, как и что переносить. К тому же, я попытался на тот же сервер чистый проект поставить (даже архив с самим вордпрессом через wget скачал), уже на стартовой странице приколы с переводом

Comment: Возможно у вас не настроена коддировка на сервере, или она не совмадает с той что у вас на локальной машине, что и приводик к кракозябрам в процессе инсталяции

Comment: В шапку со скрином с чистой установки (и пустой базой соответственно) приложил. Может быть проблема в старом мускуле? В частности pma не дает даже импортировать локальную базу. Приходится заменять CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci на CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_520_ci